# Convert large numpy arrays of BCD to decimal

Tags: python, numpy

I have binary data files in the multiple GB range that I am memory mapping with numpy.  The start of each data packet contains a BCD timestamp.  Where each hex  number is coded into the time format of 0DDD:HH:MM:SS.ssss  I need this timestamp turned into total seconds of the current year.

[image: Data Excerpt]

Example: 
The the first time stamp `0x0261 1511 2604 6002` Would be: 261:15:11:26.046002 or

```
261*86400 + 15*3600 + 11*60 + 26.046002 =  22551986.046002
```

Currently I am doing this to compute the timestamps:

```
import numpy as np
rawData  = np.memmap('dataFile.bin',dtype='u1',mode='r') 
#findFrameStart returns the index to the start of each data packet   [0,384,768,...]
fidx = findFrameStart(rawData)

# Do lots of bit shifting and multiplying and type casting....
day1  = ((rawData[fidx  ]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx  ]&0x0F)).astype('f8')
day2  = ((rawData[fidx+1]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx+1]&0x0F)).astype('f8')
hour  = ((rawData[fidx+2]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx+2]&0x0F)).astype('f8')
mins  = ((rawData[fidx+3]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx+3]&0x0F)).astype('f8')
sec1  = ((rawData[fidx+4]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx+4]&0x0F)).astype('f8')
sec2  = ((rawData[fidx+5]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx+5]&0x0F)).astype('f8')
sec3  = ((rawData[fidx+6]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx+6]&0x0F)).astype('f8')
sec4  = ((rawData[fidx+7]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx+7]&0x0F)).astype('f8')
time  = (day1*100+day2)*86400 + hour*3600 + mins*60 + sec1 + sec2/100 + sec3/10000 + sec4/1000000
```

Note I had to cast each of the intermediate vars (day1, day2, etc.) to double to get the `time` to compute correctly.

Given that there are lots of frames, `fidx` can get kind of large (~10e6 elements or more).  This results in lots of math operations, bit shifts, casting, etc. in my current method.  So far it is working OK on a smaller test file (~180ms on a 150MB data file).  However, I am worried about when I hit some larger data(4-5GB) there might be memory issues with all of the intermediate arrays.

So if possible I was looking for a different method that might shortcut some of the overhead.  The BCD to decimal operations are similar for each byte so it seems I should maybe be able to iterate over something and maybe convert an array in place ... at least reducing the memory footprint.

Any help would be appreciated.  FYI, I am using Python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following adjustments to my code.  This modifies the `time` array in place & removed the need for all of the intermediate arrays.  I haven't timed the result but it should require less memory.

```
time = np.zeros(fidx.shape,dtype='f8')
scale = np.array([8640000, 86400, 3600, 60, 1, .01, .0001, .000001],dtype='f8')
for ii,sf in enumerate(scale):
    time = time + ((rawData[fidx+ii]>>4)*10 + (rawData[fidx+ii]&0x0F))*sf
```