# Parsing Binary files that contains BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) values using Python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binary file that has some fields encoded as BCD (Binary Coded Decimal). Example as below.

14 75 26 58 87 7F (Raw bytes in hex format).

I am using (np.void, 6) to read and convert from binary file and below is the output I am getting.

b'\x14\x75\x26\x58\x87\x7F'

But I would like to get the output as '14752658877', without the fill character 'F' using numpy.

Below is the code:
with open (filename, "rb") as f:

```
    while True:

        chunk = f.read(chunksize)

        if (chunk):

            dt = np.dtype([('a','b'), ('b', '>i4'), ('c', 'S15'),('d', np.str, 7),
                                   ('e', 'S7'), ('f', np.void, 6)])

            x = np.frombuffer (chunk, dtype=dt)
            print (x)

        else:
            break
```

Also, the input file contains many fixed length binary records. What is the efficient way to convert and store it as ascii file using numpy.

Comment: Show the example code.

Comment: below is the code:with open (filename, "rb") as f:
        
        while True:
            
            chunk = f.read(chunksize)
            
            if (chunk):
                
                dt = np.dtype([('a','b'), ('b', '>i4'), ('c', 'S15'),('d', np.str, 7),
                                       ('e', 'S7'), ('f', np.void, 6)])
    
                x = np.frombuffer (chunk, dtype=dt)
                print (x)
                
            else:
                break

Comment: Please edit your original question adding the above code keeping all the formatting and indentation.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I have edited the original question to add the code.

Comment: F is not a fill character. It is part of the hex value.

Comment: @MattMessersmith: then you are stating that this is not a BCD value, but a simple hexadecimal value. According to the OP it is BCD, though. Using a non-BCD nibble as terminator makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if numpy can somehow accelerate this, but a specalized function can be quickly constructed:

```
fastDict = {16*(i//10)+(i%10):i for i in range(100)}

def bcdToInteger(bcd):
    result = 0
    while bcd and bcd[0] in fastDict:
        result *= 100
        result += fastDict[bcd[0]]
        bcd = bcd[1:]
    if bcd and bcd[0] & 0xf0 <= 0x90:
        result *= 10
        result += bcd[0]>>4
        if bcd[0] & 0xf <= 9:
            result *= 10
            result += bcd[0] & 0x0f
    return result

>>> print (bcdToInteger(b'\x14\x75\x26\x58\x87\x7F'))  # your sequence
14752658877
>>> print (bcdToInteger(b'\x12\x34\xA0'))   # first invalid nibble ends
1234
>>> print (bcdToInteger(b'\x00\x00\x99'))   # and so does an end of string
99
>>> print (bcdToInteger(b'\x1F'))           # a single nibble value
1
```

As long as you keep feeding it valid BCD bytes, it multiplies the result by 100 and adds the two new digits. Only the final byte needs some further inspection: if the highest nibble is valid, the result thus far gets multiplied by 10 and that nibble gets added. If the lowest nibble is valid as well, this is repeated.

The `fastDict` is to speed things up. It's a dictionary that returns the correct value for all 100 hex bytes from `00` to `99` so the number of actual calculations is as small as possible. You can do without the dictionary, but that means you have to do the comparisons and calculations in the `if` block for every single byte.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am using binascii.hexlify(bcdvalue).decode('utf-8').rstrip('f') to get the preferred result. But I am looking for highly efficient solution as I have many such columns. Our daily record volumes are nearly 1 Billion records.

Comment: @RajKB: Well, my solution seems pretty efficient to me. As you can see in [some other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53201592) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11668969), these use an expensive bit-shift-and-compare *twice per byte*; and my code avoids that. Yet even faster code could be written using a custom extension in C, but I'm not going to attempt that.

Comment: Hi, I am trying your solution. But I got the below error while running the code. Can you please check. 
  File "<ipython-input-9-6b5645ff319b>", line 7, in bcdToInteger
    if bcd and bcd[0] & 0xf0 <= 0x90:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Please ignore the above comment.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks alot for your answer.

Comment: Completed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.5 and up: `your_bcd_as_bytes.hex().removesuffix('F')`